# From BytesReference to AggregationBuilder in ES6

Tags: elasticsearch

I am migrating code from ES 2 to ES 6.

In ES2 there is a method that constructs aggregations from the input `Map` (`setAggregations`). This methods is removed and I am replacing it with the following code:

```
XContentBuilder xContentBuilder =
    XContentFactory.contentBuilder(Requests.CONTENT_TYPE);
xContentBuilder.map(getAggregationsBuilder(query));
BytesReference bytes = xContentBuilder.bytes();
...
```

How can I turn such `BytesReference` into `AggregationBuilder`s?